# Is Plotagraphy possible on blender possible?

Tags: filmic-blender

I have learnt plotagraphy using photoshop, but is that possible using blender

Comment: Animate some element in photograph? Yes it is possible.

Comment: It seems to me that Plotagraphy is done with a 2d flowmap and a shader. There is no tooling to do such thing in blender. It should be possible to USE flowmaps in materials.